# What is the recommended way to add first-class command line processing to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there something like [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) support in Spring Boot which provides an annotation based approach to command line argument processing? I'm interested in features such as command line binding, validation and reporting, but also the ability to map these values container managed beans. Is there a suggested integration that would give a similar feel?

I am aware that there is [`CommandLineRunner`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner) and the ability to add to the `Environment` [via command line arguments](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args), but traditional command line processing and reporting seems to not exist.

Comment: Every property on the commandline is available in the `Environment`. So you should be able to simply do something like `@Value("${your.commandline.propertyname.here}")` and have the property wired. No need for additional libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I alluded to this as well. But if `propertyname` is missing this will bomb in a most unfriendly way. There is no mechanism to list options, validate them and report on usage via the command line (stdout). There are several libraries in Java which allow you to do this. What is the recommended way to do so within a Spring Boot application?

Comment: `@Value` allows you to set a default `@Value("${your.commandline.propertyname.here:}")`. Simply add a `:` after your property and specify a default or leave empty for no value. There isn't any integration for those libraries yet nor a recommendation I believe so you are basically on your own there.

Comment: From what I understand it seems only binding is supported. I guess I will need to use another library and perform a custom integration. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently support anything out of the box so you will need to create your own solution to integrate Spring Boot with JCommander. If you have something useful that you think could be incorporated into a future release please raise an issue.